# Cant get list from received XML file

Tags: c#, linq, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml, xmldocument

This is xml that I receive:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mdpr:Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mdpr="http://...">
<mdpr:contactList>
    <mdpr:contact ID="{123456}" classID="Customer">
      <mdpr:Name>data1</mdpr:Name>
      <mdpr:TransportCode>data2</mdpr:TransportCode>
      <mdpr:ZipCode>data3</mdpr:ZipCode>
      <mdpr:City>data4</mdpr:City>
    </mdpr:contact>
    <mdpr:contact ID="{234567}" classID="Customer">
      <mdpr:Name>data5</mdpr:Name>
      <mdpr:TransportCode>data6</mdpr:TransportCode>
      <mdpr:ZipCode>data7</mdpr:ZipCode>
      <mdpr:City>data8</mdpr:City>
    </mdpr:contact>
</mdpr:contactList>
...
```

Here is how I try to get all contacts:

```
public class Contact
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string TransportCode { get; set; }
    }
...
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(doc.CreateNavigator().ReadSubtree());

            List<Contact> contacts = (from xml in xdoc.Elements("contactList").Elements("contact")
                                      select new Contact
                              {
                                  Name = xml.Element("Name").Value,
                                  TransportCode = xml.Element("TransportCode").Value
                              }).ToList();
```

But I get nothing. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does your document really use `http://...` as the mdpr namespace? (The problem is in your namespace handling.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `mdpr` namespace declared in your xml:

```
xmlns:mdpr="http://..."
```

but you are providing only local name of elements in query. E.g. you provide `contactList` name, but full name of element is `mdpr:contactList`. That's why nothing is found.

You should define `XNamespace` for your namespace and use it to create full names of elements:

```
XNamespace mdpr = "http://...";
var contacts = from c in xdoc.Root.Element(mdpr + "contactList")
                                  .Elements(mdpr + "contact")
               select new Contact {
                   TransportCode = (string)c.Element(mdpr + "TransportCode"),
                   Name = (string)c.Element(mdpr + "Name")
               };
```

Also `contactList` is not the root of document. You should search it under `Root`.

Answer (score 1):

try to specify namespace

```
string nmsp = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance/"

from xml in xdoc.Elements(nmsp+"contactList").Elements(nmsp + "contact")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(doc.CreateNavigator().ReadSubtree());
var ns = xdoc.Root.Name.Namespace;
List<Contact> contacts = (from xml in xdoc.Root.Elements(ns +"contactList").Elements(ns +"contact")
                          select new Contact
                  {
                      Name = xml.Element(ns +"Name").Value,
                      TransportCode = xml.Element(ns +"TransportCode").Value
                  }).ToList();
```